# Is the semigroup M(n, Z) finitely presented?  If so, where can I find a presentation of it?

Tags: semigroups-and-monoids

I am new to semigroup research, so I apologize if this is an easy question.

Answer (score 13):

Assuming by M(n, Z) you mean the semigroup (monoid) of n × n matrices over the integers under multiplication: no, it is not even finitely generated, because the determinant M(n, Z) → Z is multiplicative (Z denoting the monoid of integers under multiplication) and Z is not finitely generated (by the infinitude of primes).

Comment: If n=0, then M(n,Z) *is* finitely presented!  (Sorry for being obnoxious.)